# Error on Magento adminhtml category tab block override

Tags: php, cms, xml

When i try to override 
"**app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Tab**"
this Block **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product** for add new column in category product listing tab

**I have get this error**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento_new\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Tabs.php on line 153
```

**My code**

Module config xml **app\code\local\Krp\Adminhtml\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Krp_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Krp_Adminhtml>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_category_tab_product>Krp_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product</catalog_category_tab_product>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>            
        </blocks>
    </global>    
</config>
```

**app\etc\modules\Krp_Adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Krp_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Krp_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Block file code **app\code\local\Krp\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Tab\Product.php**

```
class Krp_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product{

   protected function _prepareCollection(){
    //=============== Code ==================//
   }

}
```

Comment: it means the rewrite works but it can't instantiate the new class. Can you post the full `Krp_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product`? It might be a PHP error in the class

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to configure the name of the block class.

config.xml

```
    <config>
    ...
        <global>
        ...
            <blocks>
                <krp_adminhtml>
                    <class>Krp_Adminhtml_Block</class>
                </krp_adminhtml>

                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
                        <catalog_category_tab_product>Krp_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product</catalog_category_tab_product>
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
            </blocks>
        ...
        </global>
    ...
    </config>
```